# Solve definite integral $\int_{\frac{\sqrt2}2}^{\sqrt{3}} \dfrac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^2+1}}$ by variable substitution

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, substitution

I have this integral
$$\int_{\sqrt{2}/2}^{\sqrt{3}} \dfrac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$

I have to solve it by substituting x.
I believe that the easiest way would be to substitute with $t = \sqrt{x^2+1}$. The other ways I tried didn't help me much.
so.. let $t = \sqrt{x^2+1}$. Suppose $\sqrt{6}/2 \leq t \leq 2$. In this case, we can say that $x = \varphi(t) = \sqrt{t^2-1}$. $\varphi(\sqrt{6}/2) = \sqrt{2}/2$ and $\varphi(2) = \sqrt{3}$.
Now we can substitute.
$$\int_{\sqrt{6}/2}^{2} {\dfrac{1}{\varphi(t)\sqrt{\varphi^2(t) + 1}}\varphi'(t)dt} = 
\int_{\sqrt{6}/2}^{2} {\dfrac{dt}{t\sqrt{t^2-1}}}$$

But I'm stuck here. Actually the indefinite integral of the integrand is equal to $-\ln{\sqrt{t^2-1}}$, but then by using the fundamental theorem of calculus I get a wrong result. What am I doing wrong?

The right answer is $\ln{\dfrac{3+\sqrt{6}}{3}}$. Thanks in advance.

Comment: $x=\tan\theta$ works nicely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that, with the substitution $t=\sqrt{x^2+1}$

$$ x = \sqrt{t^2-1}, \>\>\>\>\>dx = \frac t{\sqrt{t^2-1}}dt$$
Then, the integral becomes

$$\int_{\frac{\sqrt{2}}2}^{\sqrt{3}} \dfrac{1}{x\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx
= \int_{\sqrt{\frac32}}^{2} \dfrac{1}{t^2-1}dt
= \frac12 \ln\frac{t-1}{t+1}\bigg|_{\sqrt{\frac32}}^{2}\\
= \frac12\ln\left( \frac13\frac{\sqrt3+\sqrt2}{\sqrt3-\sqrt2}\right)=\ln\frac{3+\sqrt6}3
$$

Comment: I don't get the very last step. after simplifying I get $\dfrac{1}{2} \ln {\dfrac{5+2\sqrt{6}}{3}}$

Comment: @H-a-y-K - Note $5+2\sqrt6 = (\sqrt3 +\sqrt2)^2$

Comment: oohh, now I get it. thanks

Answer (score 4):

Let $$ \mathscr{I} = \int \dfrac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$
Put $ x = \dfrac1t \implies dx = -\dfrac{dt}{t^2}$
$$ \begin{align} \mathscr{I} &\ =  -\int t\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{t^2}+1}} \dfrac{dt}{t^2} \\ &\ =- \int\dfrac{dt}{\sqrt{t^2+1}} \\ &\ = - \ln \left| t + \sqrt{t^2+1} \right| + C
     \end{align} $$
Now, substitute the changed limits
$$ \begin{align} \int_{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}}^{\sqrt{3}} \dfrac{dx}{x\sqrt{x^2+1}} &\ =   \ln \left| t + \sqrt{t^2+1} \right|_{\frac{1}{\sqrt3}} ^\sqrt2 \\  &\ = \ln \dfrac{\sqrt2 + \sqrt3}{\frac{1}{\sqrt3} + \frac{2}{\sqrt3} } \\ &\ = \ln{\dfrac{3+\sqrt{6}}{3}} \end{align} $$

Answer (score 2):

This works out nicely with the trigonometric substitution  $x=\tan\theta $.  Then $\rm dx=\sec^2\theta\rm d\theta $, so we get $\int \csc\theta\rm d\theta$.

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily calculated by substituting x=1/t .

Comment: What's the point of posting this remark as an answer four hours after an answer actually developing the idea had been posted?